# How to swap elements in a array with a probability of p?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Assuming I have a numpy array `a = np.random.randint(0,20,10)` I would like to permutate its elements with a probability `p`, i.e. if `p = 0.2` each element has a 20% probability to exchange position with another element. I am aware of the `numpy.random.permutate()` function but this only allows to permutate all elements in an array. Can this be done efficiently in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to first choose which elements will be candidates to participate in the permutation.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,20,10) # original array
p = 0.2

ix = np.arange(a.size)  # indexes of a
will_swap = np.random.random(a.size) <= p  # draw which elements will be candidates for swapping
after_swap = np.random.permutation(ix[will_swap]) # permute the canidadates
ix[will_swap] = after_swap # update ix with the swapped candidates
a = a[ix]
print(a) # --> [0 1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 9]
```

Comment: This answers seems fine, but might be **slightly** wrong depending on what OP is expecting. The permutation function could leave some or all elements in their original position. So if being selected means an element could move this is correct. If it means must move then it's not quite right.